# split vector after all predefined set of elements occured

Tags: r, split

I have to do the following:

I have a vector, let as say

```r
x  <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 11, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1)
```

I have to subset the remainder of a vector after `1, 2, 3, 4` occurred at least once.
So the subset new vector would only include `4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 11, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1`.

I need a relatively easy solution on how to do this. It might be possible to do an if and while loop with breaks, but I am kinda struggling to come up with a solution.

Is there a simple (even mathematical way) to do this in R?

Comment: Do they need to be in a sequence - i.e. should `1 3 2 4` be detected or not?

Comment: If any answer has solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted". Read [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/412699) for more details about accepting an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was washed away with work (or an attempt to do some). I have accepted the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` to find where each predefined number occurs first time.

```
x[-seq(max(sapply(1:4, function(y) which(x == y)[1])))]

# [1]  4  5  5  3  2 11  1  3  3  4  1
```

***Data***

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 11, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use run length encoding for this

```
x  = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 11, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1)
encoded = rle(x)

# Pick the first location of 1, 2, 3, and 4
# Then find the max index location
indices = c(which(encoded$values == 1)[1], 
            which(encoded$values == 2)[1],
            which(encoded$values == 3)[1],
            which(encoded$values == 4)[1])

index = max(indices)

# Find the index of x corresponding to your split location
reqd_index = cumsum(encoded$lengths)[index-1] + 2 

# Print final split value
x[reqd_index:length(x)]
```

The result is as follows

```
> x[reqd_index:length(x)]
 [1]  4  5  5  3  2 11  1  3  3  4  1
```

Comment: Cool.. might not need to write the encoded$values == ... 4 x .. maybe something like max(tapply(cumsum(encoded$lengths),encoded$values,min)[c("1","2","3","4")]), will give you the position of last of 1,2,3,4

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it could probably be condensed into less code, but I prefer it to be more readable unless there is a big performance hit.